# C# Find XElement Descendant based on multiple attributes

Tags: c#, xml, xelement

I have to add information to an existing XML file. The data is going to be underneath an existing node. This has to do with Patient data, and I have to find the existing patient within the XML, so I can add the subsequent data to it. This data is encapsulated within a "PATIENTDETAILS" element.

While I found many articles on how to find a descendant via a single attribute, I need to use multiple attributes can try as I might, I can't seem to find how to use multiple attributes.

This is my current query (C#):

```
XElement patient = xmlDoc.Descendants(ns + "_PATIENTDETAILS").ToList().WHERE
(x => (string)x.Element(ns + "_PatientName") == currentPatientName).FirstOrDefault();
```

I need to add "_PatientAccNo", "_HicNo" and "_MedRecNo" to the where clause to ensure I find the right _PATIENTDETAILS before adding a new element beneath that patient with the new data.

I'm adding the new element after this query by doing:

```
XElement serviceLines = patient.Element("_PATIENTDETAILS");

xmlDoc.Element("_OCROUTPUT).Element("_PATIENTDETAILS").Add(new XELEMENT("_SERVICELINES",
new XElement(name, data),
Blah blah blah
```

If someone can give me an example of using multiple where clauses in finding a Descendant, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine conditions with a logical **and** which is `&&` in C#.

```cs
XElement patient = xmlDoc.Descendants(ns + "_PATIENTDETAILS")
    .Where(x => (string)x.Element(ns + "_PatientName") == currentPatientName &&
                (string)x.Element(ns + "another element") == anotherValue &&
                (string)x.Element(ns + "yet another element") == yetAnotherValue)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

See also: [Conditional logical AND operator &&](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators#conditional-logical-and-operator-).

And also the `.ToList()` in there can be dropped. It adds no value.

Comment: Thank you, I was trying that (using &&), but I see where I made my syntax error, I appreciate it very much......that worked.

Really appreciate it.